# npm-tfs-unlock package on TFS

Tags: c#, node.js, jenkins, tfs, npm

I have a problem with a npm package the tfs-unlock (I'm using grunt)

This is the message that I get from server when trying to build.

> [exec] [4mRunning "tfs-unlock:checkout" (tfs-unlock) task[24m
>        [exec] [31m>> [39mChild process exited with code # 1.
>        [exec] [33mWarning: Task "tfs-unlock:checkout" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m
>        [exec] 
>        [exec] [31mAborted due to warnings.[39m

and this is the configuration of the task

```
'tfs-unlock': {
            'checkout': {
                'options': {
                    'tfsPath': ["vs2013", "bit64"], 
                    'action': 'checkout'
                },
                'files': {
                    'src': ['js/*.js', 'js/*.min.js', 'css/*.css']
                }
            }
        }
```

Has anyone who used it, have had this issue? if so, why this error appears? how to make it work?
Thank you

PS: locally works perfect, it does not complain of anything.
I'm using Jenkins and Octopus for automatic build and deploy.

When Jenkins builds, changes should be applied (this is the step where the "tfs-unlock:checkout" fails says that the "checkout child" does not exist, when clearly it does exist , how else could this work locally right?)

I'm working behind a PROXY but to handle this I use this file which is targeted by an Ant step

my.xml configuration

```
   <target name="build" description="generate files with grunt">
      <exec executable="cmd" dir="./" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="/C" />
        <arg value="npm"/>
        <arg value="config"/>
        <arg value="set"/>
        <arg value="proxy"/>
        <arg value="http://my_Address/"/>
        <arg value="--global"/>
      </exec>
      <echo message="Installing Deps ..." />
        <exec executable="cmd" dir="./" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="/C" />
            <arg value="npm"/>
            <arg value="install"/>
        </exec>
        <echo message="generate files..." />
        <exec executable="cmd" dir="./" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="/C" />
            <arg value=".\node_modules\.bin\grunt" />
        </exec>
        <echo message="Done" />
    </target>
```

Comment: It is clearly a wrapper around TF.exe; can you hand the original command line? Maybe you are using server workspaces and a file is locked by another user

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure your configuration and option  with `grunt-tfs-unlock` is correct without any problem.  Details please refer this link [grunt-tfs-unlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-tfs-unlock)

Moreover, if it's still not wrok. You can also use the workaround--using the `grunt-shell` task which leaves you more in charge of the configuration.

Here is a  [example of using TFS check out with Grunt](https://gist.github.com/localnerve/6112944). This link demonstrates the 'tf checkout' command. However you could also create any other tf command with this pattern.